# Fastlane Gym Archive Error on Xcode 14, modulemap not found / ld: library not found

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

I have been stuck at this issue for a couple of days now, with no solution yet. `yarn react-native run-ios` works as expected, but when I'm trying to build the app with Fastlane, it fails at the archive-step of Gym (`bundle exec fastlane staging`), it fails with the following output:

```
[15:43:43]: ▸ <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bupcdothwllbfwavuwwinjrmdvlb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/VisionCamera/VisionCamera.modulemap' not found
[15:43:43]: ▸ <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bupcdothwllbfwavuwwinjrmdvlb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

I have configured a Swift bridging header for my app, and I am currently on React Native v0.71.4. I have followed the migration guide when upgrading from 0.70.7 to 0.71.4.

In Podfile, no env-vars are set. If I try to set `USE_FRAMEWORKS=static`, I get an error on `yarn react-native run-ios` with `'VisionCamera/FrameProcessorPlugin.h' file not found` and `RCTAppDelegate.h file not found` on Fastlane gym.

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!
# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = 'arm64'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
    end
  end

  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = 'YES'
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = 'arm64'
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
  end
  react_native_post_install(
    installer,
    # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
    # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
    :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
  )
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end
````

Fastfile:

```
default_platform :ios

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end

  lane :staging do # Build staging and deploy to testflight
    sh "yarn env-staging"
    match(type: "appstore")
    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: "./ios/MyApp.xcodeproj",
      build_number: ENV['CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM']
    )
    gym(
      clean: true,
      scheme: "MyApp",
      project: "./ios/MyApp.xcodeproj",
      export_method: "app-store",
      output_directory: "./build-tools/deploy/data"
    )
    pilot(
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
  end
end
```

Looking further into this issue, I can see that the pods generated by Cocoapods in `bundle exec pod install` contain release.xcconfig referring to `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` as the root of the modulemaps, with `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`.

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -fmodule-map-file="${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VisionCamera/VisionCamera.modulemap" -fmodule-map-file="${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/vision-camera-code-scanner/vision_camera_code_scanner.modulemap" ....
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -D COCOAPODS -Xcc -fmodule-map-file="${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VisionCamera/VisionCamera.modulemap" -Xcc -fmodule-map-file="${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/vision-camera-code-scanner/vision_camera_code_scanner.modulemap" ....
```

I have looked at similar problems where one solution was to remove all the lines referring to the modulemaps in question, which then leads me to the next error:

```
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
```

Looking at the release.xcconfig again, I can see that the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` for CocoaAsyncSocket also refers to the same `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` as before:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/usr/lib/swift/${PLATFORM_NAME}" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/CocoaAsyncSocket"
```

Removing this again yields an error with `ld: framework not found hermes`.

I have also tried other solutions that might include something along the lines of "Delete Pods-dir and Podfile.lock, clean build, clean DerivedData-dir, change build target in Xcode" where none have worked so far.

Hopefully there is a "permanent" solution to this which is possible to implement during CI-build as well, and not just a "hack" where we modify the pods directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted solution to this problem elsewhere is to make sure that we are using .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj. This is true for this case as well, and more specifically, the way to accomplish this with Fastlane is to update the gym-config, as such:

```
    gym(
      clean: true,
      scheme: "MyApp",
      workspace: "./ios/MyApp.xcworkspace", # Previously 'project: "./ios/Myapp.xcodeproj"'
      export_method: "app-store",
      output_directory: "./build-tools/deploy/data"
    )
```